# How to get redis hit ratio?

Tags: python, redis

I'm using redis as a cache server. I can connect to it with my credentials. How to find out what is hit ratio (hit rate) of my redis instance?

Answer (score 6):

You need to get `keyspace_hits` and `keyspace_misses` from your redis database. There are several ways how to do it.

**From command-line:**

```
$> redis-cli info
...
keyspace_hits:213
keyspace_misses:45
...
```

**From python** (you need to install package "redis"):

```
In [1]: import redis
In [2]: client = redis.StrictRedis(host='redis', port=6379, db=0)
In [3]: client.info()
Out[3]:
{...
u'keyspace_hits': 213,
u'keyspace_misses': 45,
...}
```

Then you can calculate hit ratio:

### hit_ratio = keyspace_hits / (keyspace_hits + keyspace_misses)

In our case it would be

hit_rate = *213 / (213 + 45) = 0,8255813953*

That's 82.56% hit rate.